# How to listen to events across multiple components?

Tags: java, events, vaadin

I have a project using Spring Boot and Vaadin. In this project I have a MainView that contains some Dialog components and upon closing these dialogues I would like the MainView to show a little plus button on the page and clicking this button would reopen the dialog (in the future). For this I have created a custom component event, added a listener for this event to the main view component and I "fire" the event after closing the dialog. The problem is that the MainView component registers the listener to its own event bus, but when the event is fired (from the dialog component) there are no listeners. Here is my code:

```
public class ComponentCloseEvent extends ComponentEvent<CustomDialog> {

  public ComponentCloseEvent(CustomDialog source, boolean fromClient) {
    super(source, fromClient);
  }
}
    
// constructor for MainView

public MainView() {
  addListener(ComponentCloseEvent.class, e -> System.out.println("I listened to the event!"));
  add(new CustomDialog());
}

// method inside CustomDialog

private ButtonEx createCloseButton() {
  return new Button("Close", e -> {
    fireEvent(new ComponentCloseEvent(this, true));
    close();
  });
}
```

When I debug the code the `fireEvent` is not called because the function `hasListeners` returns `false`:

```
protected void fireEvent(ComponentEvent<?> componentEvent) {
  if (hasListener(componentEvent.getClass())) {
    getEventBus().fireEvent(componentEvent);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the UI event bus.
`MainView` can attach a listener to UI in the `onAttach()` method, and the component can fire events using `ComponentUtil.fireEvent()` utility.

Take a look at this example https://cookbook.vaadin.com/ui-eventbus

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for, but couldn't find on my own.